# use css body css class for menu

Tags: html, css

I recently get task and they explain this task in the following way

**The navigation must be styled using the *:hover pseudo class*, while the *active menu point must use the body class***

my question is the second one i.e. *the *active menu point must use the body class*. Following is html snippet.

```
<body class="home">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li id="btnHome"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li id="btnAbout"><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li id="btnContact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li id="btnLinks"><a href="#">Links</a></li>
            </ul>
                    </div>
             </div>
     </div>
```

How can I use body class to for menu items so when user is on home page then home link will be active using css. Same goes with the other links?

Answer (score 1):

I think that means for every page the body class changes, so for the HomePage you have the class home, for the AboutPage you have the class about....

```
.home #btnHome {
    /* active home menu code */
}

.about #btnAbout {
    /* active about menu code */
}
```

Is that what you need?

Comment: Sort of but can I make it more generic? I mean rather writing code for every link just use one while not adding extra class and id to these elements.

Comment: You may not add an id for every link in the menu. You may use *.home #nav li:nth-child(0): {...}*. But you can't skip the creation of a new selector.

Comment: Seeing as your task says that you have to use the body class for the active link there's only so much you can do to make it more 'generic'. Asuming that all active link are gonna have the same class, you could bundle them together in a one css-rule e.g **.home #btnHome, .about #btnAbout, .contact #btnContact, .links #btnLink{}**.

You could also create an _active_ class for the links, that way you can target them like so **.home .active, .about .active, .contact .active, .links .active {}**.